# Reinstall bootloader (systemd-boot or GRUB) without external media?

Tags: arch-linux, dual-boot, boot-loader

I recently updated the BIOS on my Lenovo Miix-700 and immediately regretted it. I was hoping to fix a problem with the webcam after a Windows update, but unsurprisingly the BIOS update overwrote the EFI partition AND didn't fixed the webcam. I tried to make a new Arch bootable USB so I could chroot and reinstall but it turns out the update knocked out the single USB port too (hub malfunction?). Now my whole digital life is on a partition I have no access to*. I wanted to ask on the Arch forums, but the registration question requires that you are able to run a line of code under Arch so here we are. Any suggestions?

*I can technically access the files using a program in Windows, but I have no access to the various programs needed to use those files.

EDIT: As suggested by telcoM. Nothing jumps out as being Arch related.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /enum firmware

Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bootmgr}
                        {d7ec5199-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
                        {d7ec519a-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
                        {d7ec519b-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
                        {d7ec519c-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
                        {d7ec519d-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
timeout                 0

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {86dba24d-a094-11e9-9adb-bd1dd03f5338}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec5196-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             Setup

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec5197-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             Boot Menu

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec5198-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             Diagnostic Splash

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec5199-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             ATA HDD: RTHMB128VBM4EWDL

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec519a-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             USB FDD:

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec519b-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             USB CD:

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec519c-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             USB HDD:

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {d7ec519d-eb30-11e9-bd4c-806e6f6e6963}
description             PCI LAN:
```

Comment: I surely requires a deeper look, but one think came to my mind instantly. You can install VirtualBox in Windows and configure it to use your partition as a *raw disk*. Then you can boot Arch or whatever in VirtualBox and access your partition. I've often used VirtualBox like that to install Linux to a disk without booting from USB or DVD.

Comment: I would find it surprising that a BIOS update would overwrite the EFI partition, and that would have damaged Windows too. More likely it just wiped out the EFI NVRAM boot variables. Start a Windows command prompt as administrator, and run `bcdedit /enum firmware`, or run `efibootmgr -v` in Linux. If the output does not reference Arch at all, you've lost your NVRAM settings in the BIOS update.

Comment: @telcoM So how would I restore the NVRAM settings?

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion. I will try it out.

Comment: @Robert That's good advice for some other types of problems, but in this case it looks like what is needed is to recreate the UEFI NVRAM variables on the actual physical host, which cannot be done from within VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the BIOS update did indeed wipe out your existing EFI NVRAM boot variables. Windows has recovered either with the help of built-in firmware support or by "self-healing": Windows places its UEFI bootloader also at `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.efi` on the ESP partition, which is the fallback UEFI bootloader in case there is no NVRAM boot variables explicitly identifying a bootloader for the disk. This allows Windows to load, and then it will automatically restore its NVRAM boot variable if it finds it's missing.

Since the original UEFI NVRAM contents have been lost in the BIOS update, if you had customized your system's Secure Boot keys, those settings may also have returned to factory defaults. You might have to disable Secure Boot for now, until you regain access to Arch and can restore those customizations by following the original Secure Boot key customization procedure again.

For Arch, the restoration of the NVRAM boot variable is complicated by the fact that there are various ways Arch UEFI boot can be set up. It might use EFISTUB, or GRUB, or rEFInd. So the first step is to gain access to the EFI System Partition and find out what's actually in there.

---

In Windows, you can access the EFI System Partition by starting Command Prompt *as an Administrator*, and then running these commands:

```
mountvol X: /S
X:
dir
```

You should now see a list of the root directory of the EFI System Partition. If you want GUI access, you could run `start explorer` to get a standard File Explorer windows running as Administrator. Be very careful with that window, as you will not be protected by the standard UAC prompts when using that particular window.

If you are using EFISTUB to boot Arch, there might be `vmlinuz.efi` or `vmlinuz-linuz` and an initramfs file `initramfs-linux.img` right in the root directory of the EFI System Partition. Make a note of their exact pathnames. They might also be in the `\EFI\Arch` sub-directory, depending on exactly which version of the installation instructions you originally followed.

If you are using a bootloader like GRUB or rEFInd, they will be located in a sub-directory of the `\EFI` directory. Move into it and look at the directory listing (either using the File Explorer window, or by `cd EFI` and then `dir` again). You should see at least two directories named `Microsoft` and `boot`. The `Microsoft` directory contains the Windows UEFI bootloader, and the `boot` directory contains just the essential part to start it in case the NVRAM boot variables have been lost.

For your Arch installation, there might be a subdirectory `\EFI\Arch` (in case of using GRUB), or `\EFI\refind` (in case of using rEFInd). Move into that directory and confirm the name of the actual bootloader file: it might be `\EFI\Arch\grubx64.efi` or `\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi`.

Once you know the pathname of the Arch bootloader on ESP, you can create a NVRAM boot variable for it. In Windows, you can do this with the `bcdedit` commands:

```
bcdedit /create /d "Arch Linux" {fwbootmgr}
```

This command will output a GUID string, which you will need on any subsequent `bcdedit` commands; I will call it `{GUID}` for brevity.

```
bcdedit /set {GUID} device partition=X:
bcdedit /set {GUID} path <your bootloader pathname here>
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} default {GUID}
```

Depending on your version of Windows, the last command might return an error. In that case, use an alternate form for it:

```
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {GUID} /addfirst
```

Finally, disconnect your access to the ESP. Close the File Explorer window running as Administrator if you started one, and then run these commands in the Command Prompt:

```
c:
mountvol X: /D
```

---

If you can boot your system to some kind of Linux (in native UEFI style, so that the UEFI runtime services will be available to the kernel), you can use the `efibootmgr` command to recreate the NVRAM variable in a considerably simpler command:

```
efibootmgr --create --disk /dev/sda --loader <your bootloader pathname here> --label "Arch Linux Bootloader" --verbose
```

Adjust the value of the `--disk` option to match the actual disk that contains the ESP partition, if necessary.

**Note:** since Linux shells use backslashes as special escape characters, you must either convert the Windows-style backslashes in the bootloader pathname to Linux-style forward slashes, or double the backslashes when entering the bootloader pathname for `efibootmgr`, so that your bootloader pathname might look like this on the `efibootmgr` command line:

```
efibootmgr [...] --loader \\EFI\\Arch\\grubx64.efi [...]
```

If you are using EFISTUB, you will need extra parameters for the `efibootmgr` command to specify the Linux kernel boot parameters, including the name of the initramfs file:

```
efibootmgr --disk /dev/sdX --part Y --create --label "Arch Linux" --loader /vmlinuz-linux --unicode 'root=PARTUUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX rw initrd=\initramfs-linux.img' --verbose
```

Specifying those extra parameters with the Windows `bcdedit` command might or might not be possible - unfortunately I cannot find the Windows syntax for it right now.

Comment: I tried this twice with Secure Boot enabled/disabled, and it didn't work either way. `bcdedit /enum firmware` doesn't show the new variable. I did have an issue with the line `bcdedit /create /d "Arch Linux" {fwbootmgr}`; it gives the error that "a description must be provided". I used `bcdedit /create /d "Arch Linux" /inherit fwbootmgr`, which was successful but I'm not sure its equivalent.

Comment: Is `{fwbootmgr}` in `bcdedit /create /d "Arch Linux" {fwbootmgr}` supposed to be the identifier for the new variable?

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work by using `bcdedit /copy` to copy the Windows Boot Mangager `{bootmgr}` and then change the path. Thank you for your help.